# Импорт статических переменных

Tags: java

Если я создам класс, то где буду хранить все переменные, которые могут использоваться в разных классах?

В статических переменных, а потом импортировать их в классы?

```
import static Const.*;
```

Стоит ли так делать?

Получается, импортируются все переменные, и они будут храниться в памяти каждого класса? Или будут импортироваться только те, которые будут использоваться в классе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Статические переменные будут созданы всегда, в единственном экземпляре по определению. Данная конструкция просто позволяет вам избежать необходимости писать каждый раз `Const.SOME_VALUE` вместо просто `SOME_VALUE`. Поскольку кроме некоторой путаницы (откуда взялась эта константа) это мало чем помогает, данная конструкция является не рекомендуемой к употреблению.

Comment: Я бы не сказал, что это вносит путаницу. Код становится проще читать и писать, а для того, чтобы посмотреть, откуда взялась константа, существуют IDE.

Comment: @zzashpaupat дело вкуса и конкретной ситуации, но в большинстве случаев засорение глобольного списка имён скорее плохо чем хорошо.

Comment: у меня вопрос в том будут импортироваться все статические переменные или только те которые используются в классе, то при работе программы в памяти этого будут храниться все переменные даже те которые не используются, ведь если я в классе Const буду храниться 1000 переменных и буду импортировать все статические переменные в 100 классов тогда получается в памяти будут храниться они все или я что то не понимаю

Comment: @JTan если ваш "статический" класс загружен, то будут созданы все его статические переменные независимо от того используются они или нет. Как я уже писал выше, все статические переменные будут созданы в единственном экземпляре, ваш `import static Const.*;` это не более чем удобство обращения к статическим переменным класса (как при использовании "обычных" imports).

Comment: получается они будут храниться в единственном экземпляре а не в каждом классе куда я импортировал? и если я изменю из одного из классов поле этого класса оно изменится в другом классе.

Comment: @JTan да верно. Статические переменные = глобальные переменные.